# unable to install firebase using npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

Hi I am following a tutorial using firebase (its quite an old version) when I try to install firebase it will not install as all.

I am using npm install firebase@4.13 --save, i have also used npm install firebase@4.13 --save --force -g but get the same issue.

I have tried to clean the cache using npm cache clean --force.

below is my full error report, could someone please help with this as I really have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks

I have tried:

uninstalling node and reinstalling
cleaning the cache
different npm install statements
restarting the project again

I can provide the error report but it is 1644 lines long so it wont allow me to post it with this.

Comment: You can share the first 10 lines of error report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.